# I can't open tty1 in terminal

Tags: command-line, tty

I'm doing a lab. After I add new users to a group, I'm supposed to do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> to open `tty1` in the terminal. I have a Dell, and it was programmed to open the Control Panel. I disabled hot keys, but now <kbd>f1</kbd> doesn't do anything. I can open `tty2/3/4`, but my code is programmed for `tty1`. I have tried it full screen and half screen, but neither way opens `tty1` in my terminal.

Comment: How did you disable your hot keys?   All 7 TTY sessions are started when Ubuntu boots up.  Have you rebooted since you disabled your hot keys?

Comment: Searched up how to disable hot keys on dell. Have to go into the properties and go into the dell control panel and disable them. It's a timed lab, so I believe so yeah. I have to reserve sessions of time to use Ubuntu through netlab for coastline.

Comment: OK, and you are indeed running a version of Ubuntu, correct?

Comment: Go into TTY2 with Ctrl+Alt+F2, then try going to TTY1 with Alt+F1

Comment: Seems like you're running Ubuntu in a virtual machine, right? And Windows is the host OS?